# Offset effect to create a shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been following a tutorial but I can't figure out how to create the shadow effect on the lower curve. Does it have to be a path? Right now it's a filled object.

[image: Wanted effect]

[image: This is where I am now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make a Transparency Mask

- Create a path where the shadow will be > 100% Black
- Cut this path
- Select the curve and from the **Transparency Panel** make a **Transparency Mask**
- Uncheck Clip
- Click the right square from the panel to activate the mask area
- **Menu Edit** > **Past in Front**
- Click the left square from the panel to activate the editing area

[image: Transparency Mask]

**Create the shadow path:**

- Using the **Direct Selection Tool**, select the two points from the main shape to create the shadow
- **Copy**/**Paste in Front**
- Delete the points from the ends
- **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**
- Stroke = 100% Black
- Duplicate to the left
- Select the top points > **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**
- Select the bottom points > **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**
- Fill it 100% Black, Stroke none
- Select it with the main shape an make the **Transparency Mask**

[image: Path]

Comment: There is no need to cut and paste. The opacity mast will always be the top object. Just select both and make the clip.

Comment: OK. In the tutorial it seems that he's not using the opacity mask to cut out. But more likely an Offset effect. Look here: https://www.instagram.com/p/BjspHBWhdGP/?taken-by=shibupg

Comment: Yes, create a path by making copy / paste of the central path, add a white stroke, expand it, make Minus Front with a rectangle at the top and another rectangle at the bottom. Finally delete the unnecessary side. Disadvantage: the process is longer, create one more path and it does not work on a background other than white. With Transparency Mask you get all that in just one stroke and possible to place in any background color.

Comment: The opacity mask method works alright :-) But I have to create the path manually yes? Is there a way expand the width of the path in only one direction in order to create the gap?

Comment: I added a gif at the answer.